# Remove offline_access scope in identity server 4 we;;-known configuration

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, openid

I have .NET Core app with IdentityServer 4 in it.

I want to hide/remove one entry of "scopes_supported" under .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint.

Basically it shows all my custom scopes, but one is automatically generated, maybe anyone can help me hiding it?

```
 ....
  "scopes_supported": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "custom_scope1",
    "custom_scope2",
    "offline_access" //  <----- this one worries me, how to remove it
  ],
 ....
```

Comment: why do you want to hide it? you use it when you want a refresh token

Comment: We do not use refresh tokens in our flow, plus under Clients table, on all clients you can set AllowOfflineAccess true/false, all our clients has False set. So there is no point showing that, when our customers tends to ask about it, so we want to remove that entry to avoid questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for the discovery document creation that adds the offline_Access scope is found [here](https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer/blob/4425c0747155a5dce5f759255a448e91c9252dee/src/IdentityServer/ResponseHandling/Default/DiscoveryResponseGenerator.cs#L242).

If you disable the Options.Discovery.ShowApiScopes flag, then it will not be shown, but you won't see the ApiScopes either it seems.

See [this page](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/discovery.html#discovery) for how to disable that flag or you disable it as shown below.

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Discovery.ShowIdentityScopes = false;
    options.Discovery.ShowApiScopes = false;
    options.Discovery.ShowClaims = false;
    options.Discovery.ShowExtensionGrantTypes = false;
});
```

It seems you can't just hide the offline_scope.

Comment: Thank you, for a good point. But however, maybe you know if there's a way to actually disable that offline_access scope, not just hide ?

Comment: You could always download IdentityServer yourself and modify it, build and use it?

Comment: Sorry if I sound a bit stupid, but what is the difference between "downloading identity server" and using it as a nuget package? Because I thought it is the same thing, I own that authentication server, and my clients are seeing "offline_access" as an option, I want to remove it

Comment: I mean, download the IdentityServer sourcecode and compile it yourself. But I wouldn't recomend that route. I don't think offline_access is really an option as you in many cases do want it so the client application can refresh the access token at will. Alternativey, you can submit a feature request to the IdentityServer team.

Comment: Hard to believe, that so many applications, that has hidden/removed "offline_access" from discovery scopes, has downloaded and recompiled identity server themselves and not just used one or another option using Nuget package for example. But thank you for helping with investigation.